# Question on contact metric manifolds which Reeb vector field isn't an eigenvector of the Ricci operator?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249187/how-to-construct-an-example-of-contact-metric-manifold-with-the-following-condit) I asked a question with no answer. In this topic I have another question:

**Question:**
Can anybody construct an example of 5 dimensional contact metric manifold $(M,\eta,\xi,g,\varphi)$ such that $Q\xi\neq\lambda\xi$,
where $Q$ is Ricci operator and $\lambda$ is a smooth function on $M$. In 3 dimensional case I found such example.